# How can I set the ViewModel property for a DataTemplate in a Binding Context within a ListView?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvm, xamarin.android

## Setting ViewModel Property in DataTemplate Binding Context

In my application I have a ListView bound to a ObservableCollection. I'm trying to set the DataTemplate of the list view to my xaml file called CourseCard and set the BindingContext of the CourseCard to my CourseCardViewModel AND set the Course property of that view model to the Course object in the list.

Here is my code:

```
MainPage.xaml
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Courses}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <views:CourseCard>
                            <views:CourseCard.BindingContext>
                                <vm:CourseCardViewModel>
                                    <vm:CourseCardViewModel.Course>
                                        <Binding Path="." />
                                    </vm:CourseCardViewModel.Course>
                                </vm:CourseCardViewModel>
                            </views:CourseCard.BindingContext>
                        </views:CourseCard>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

Is this even possible? Am I making it too complicated? The goal is to have dynamic set of CourseCards appear on the mainpage.xaml representing Course objects. I'm still learning so go easy on me.

The IDE doesn't like my code saying:

Error   XFC0009 No property, BindableProperty, or event found for "Course", or mismatching type between value and property.

I do have a public property in my CourseCardViewModel :

```
//CourseCardViewModel.cs
    private Course _course;
            public Course Course
            {
                get { return _course; }
                set
                {
                    _course = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
```

**EDIT**

Apologies for not giving more context. Here is more detail about what I'm trying to do:

I have a MainPage.xaml and a MainPageViewModel.cs

I have a CourseCard.xaml and a CourseCardViewModel.cs

The ObservableCollection "Courses" lives in the MainPageViewModel.cs

I want a list of CourseCards on the MainPage.xaml while maintaining the properties and methods of the CourseCardViewModel that handles events and data for the CourseCards.

Should I instead scrap the CourseCard viewModel and move the properties and methods to my mainpageviewmodel to make it less complicated?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve thanks for commenting! I made some changes to describe more accurately what I'm trying to do. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was overthinking my issue by mistakenly thinking that the CourseCard content view was not showing for each course object in Courses because I wasn't getting the BindingContext set correctly. Turns out I never initialized my Courses ObservableCollection before adding dummy Courses to it.

So here is my code now:

Not sure why but it only displays as a collection view.

```
MainPage.xaml
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Courses}">
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <views:CourseCard/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
```

And here is Courses in my MainPageViewModel.cs:

```
private ObservableCollection<Course> _courses;
        public ObservableCollection<Course> Courses
        {
            get { return _courses; }
            set
            {
                if (_courses != value)
                {
                    _courses = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Courses));
                }
            }
        }
```

The issue was in my LoadCourses method I was missing the initialization before adding dummy courses to it.

```
Courses = new ObservableCollection<Course>(); // Needed this line

            Courses.Add(new Course { Title = "New Course 1" });  // Add a dummy course
            Courses.Add(new Course { Title = "New Course 2" });  // Add a dummy course
            Courses.Add(new Course { Title = "New Course 3" });  // Add a dummy course
```

In my troubleshooting I moved the functionality of the CourseCardViewModel to the codebehind in CourseCard.xaml.cs next I'll try to move it back and see if it still works.

Setting the datatype at the top of my CourseCard.xaml seemed to help with the binding to Course properties.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:fontAwesome="clr-namespace:FontAwesome" 
             xmlns:data="clr-namespace:C971_Performance_Assessment.Data"
             x:Class="C971_Performance_Assessment.Views.CourseCard"
             x:DataType="data:Course"> //This line
```

Thanks to both of you that helped answer my question and helped me realize that I was both overthinking it and there were other ways to set the BindingContext to a different ViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you don't have to use an extra CourseCardViewModel for CourseCard. You could set all properties or event for CourseCard on MainPageViewModel. That will be much less complicated like your said. Before going on, you could learn something about [Bindable properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/bindable-properties)(if necessary）and [Relative bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/relative-bindings).

If you want to set the BindingContext of CourseCard to MainPageViewModel. That's easy to use the following code:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         ...
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProjectName.ViewModelFolder"
         x:Class="MyProjectName.MainPage">

<DataTemplate>
    <ViewCell>
        <views:CourseCard BindingContext="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:MainPageViewModel}}, Path=.}"/>
    </ViewCell>
```

The default BindingContext for each CourseCard in DataTemplate is corresponding Course in your Courses. After using above code, we successfully change the BindingContext to the MainPageViewModel.

Then you can just move all properties or command from CourseCardViewModel to MainPageViewModel.

============================Origin Answer======================

> A ListView is populated with data using the ItemsSource property, which can accept any collection implementing IEnumerable

In ViewModel, you may create a collection of Course:

```
public ObservableCollection<Course> Courses { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Course>();
```

Then in xaml, just set the ItemsSource for CollectionView:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Courses}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <views:CourseCard/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

The default BindingContext for each CourseCard in DataTemplate is corresponding Course in your Courses.

Don't forget to set the BindingContext for the page in code behind:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.BindingContext = new CourseCardViewModel();
}
```

For more info, you may refer to [ListView Data Sources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/data-and-databinding)

Hope it works

Comment: Thanks for the help! I added more context to my question as I realized it wasn't clear what exactly I'm trying to do. Would appreciate a second look if you have the time!

Comment: @MegaMarsh I have updated my answer. If you have any question, feel free to ask.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply! Your answer helped get me in the right direction. I mistakenly thought that part of the reason none of my CourseCards were displaying was because I had a viewmodel for my CourseCards. Turns out I didn't initialize my Observable Collection before adding test courses to it. I'll post above what my code looks like now.

Answer (score 0):

- **Remove** your attempt to set BindingContext in ItemTemplate.
  Delete this xaml:

```xml
<!-- Delete this -->
<views:CourseCard.BindingContext>
    <vm:CourseCardViewModel>
       <vm:CourseCardViewModel.Course>
            <Binding Path="." />                                    
       </vm:CourseCardViewModel.Course>
    </vm:CourseCardViewModel>
</views:CourseCard.BindingContext>
```

- CourseCard should do `BindingContext = new CourseCardViewModel();` in its constructor (after InitializeComponent()), OR equivalent in its XAML (not shown).
  Ex:

```cs
public CourseCard()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    BindingContext = new CourseCardViewModel();
}
```

Or if that vm is a parameter to constructor,
`public CourseCard(CourseCardViewModel ccvm)`, then
`BindingContext = ccvm;`.